# How would i access this tag <div u="slides" > through external CSS ?

Tags: jssor

I m having issues in manipulating Cascading Style Sheets of this particular tag.I want an external Cascading Style Sheets to change its styling.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can specify css for 'slides' container in following manner,

```
<div id="yourid" class="yourclass" u="slides" ...>

<style>
#yourid {
}

.yourclass {
}
</style>
```

Comment: Does it affect the images or i have to keep images in other class to re size them according to my need.

Comment: No, it doesn't affect image. You can specify class for image element.

Comment: Jssor Slider will auto adjust layout for image with u="image" attribute (<img u="image" ...) according to $FillMode option. And it will not for normal image element (<img ...), you can customize it with your own class.

Answer (score 0):

A bit more here....

```
<style>
  div[u=slides] {
  }
</style>
```